# Publisher that emits new values when the cache is updated

Tags: caching, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, project-reactor, spring-cache

Is there a way to wrap the cache and create a publisher that will emit new values?

I have a data pipeline (courtesy of Kafka Streams) and a requirement to serve the result via GraphQL subscription. To avoid having to deal with ~10k temporary consumers, I want to preload the cache. Basically I need a `Publisher` or kotlin coroutines `Flow` that will wrap the cache, listen for an update event and emit a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, not with [Spring's Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache) (API or Annotations), directly.

In the application layer, you would need to write an AOP Aspect encapsulating the functionality to emit an event via the publisher after a cache update, then combine and order your event emitting (*Spring*) AOP Aspect/Advice with the Caching Advice applied to your (e.g.) `@Cacheable` annotated application service method by *Spring's Cache Abstraction*. This is possible to do if you want to keep this concern with the application logic, which might arguably be more reusable.

However, an alternative, maybe easier approach (depending on your *caching provider*) is to simply implement a callback interface provided by your *caching provider* itself, if indeed such a callback exists.

For example, with [Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/), which can [serve](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot-data-geode-build/current/reference/html5/#geode-caching-provider) as a *caching provider* in *Spring's Cache Abstraction* (& framework) you can implement an application-specific Apache Geode [`CacheListener`](https://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheListener.html) with your desired behavior depending on the type of cache update (e.g. create, update, destroy, invalidation (usually triggered by expiration), etc). This interface is *caching provider* dependent, though. But, on the flip side, this would be more reliable in terms of the cache was definitely altered as a result of the caching operation triggered by the `@Cacheable` application service method, for instance.

Anyway, I hope this gives you some ideas.  Mileage varies.

Cheers!